Change order of words in LaTeX tcolorbox or tcbtheorem
Along my work I have faced with the following problem:
I would like to create a theorem environment with \newtcbtheorem, but the text need to be in Hungarian language. The original command creates the heading in the order: number, theorem type; so for example the following code:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}


\newcounter{exc_counter}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter=exc_counter,number format=\arabic]{exercise_easy}{Feladat}
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{exc} 

\newtheorem*{solution}{Megoldás}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise_easy}{}{exc:konnyufeladat}
Some easy exercise.
\begin{solution}
Some easy solution of an easy exercise.
\end{solution}
\end{exercise_easy}

\end{document}

will create a coloured box environment with the title "Feladat 3" (in English: Excercise 3). However, Hungarian grammar requires it in the following form: "3. Feladat", say I need to take a dot after the number, and change the order of words.
How is that possible to change the declaration of these environments to produce a header of the theorem environment in such a way that I'd like to have?
Thanks for your help!

This would warrant a feature request for tcolorbox.
You can add a key based on the already present
theorem number and name

with the difference that a period is added after the number.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% not t1enc
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% define a new key for tcolorbox based on 'theorem name and number'
\tcbset
  {
    hungarian~theorem/.code =
      {
       \cs_set_eq:NN \__tcobox_theo_format:nn \__tcobox_theo_format_hungarian:nn
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \__tcobox_theo_format_hungarian:nn
  {
    \__tcobox_theo_format_name_number:nn { #2. } { #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{exc_counter}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtcbtheorem[
  use counter=exc_counter,
  number format=\arabic
]{exercise_easy}{Feladat}{
  colback=green!5,
  colframe=green!35!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  hungarian theorem,
}{exc} 

\newtheorem*{solution}{Megoldás}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise_easy}{}{exc:konnyufeladat}
Some easy exercise.
\begin{solution}
Some easy solution of an easy exercise.
\end{solution}
\end{exercise_easy}

\end{document}

Load \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} rather than the outdated t1enc package.


This is a really useful answer, thank you! And also thanks for your suggestion about the font package!
